# jquery navigation bar: sub sub menu's onmouseover and onmouseout not working smoothly

Tags: jquery, navigationbar

when I hover on #subsubmenu1, onmouseover and onmouseout event handlers are not working smoothly. When i try to hover on the Company Price link, immediately #subsubmenu1 dissappears. Where am I going wrong?

My code at: http://jsfiddle.net/DhA2Z/6/

thank you.

Comment: You just need some [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)'s

Comment: Ok, i will try out stop() and let you know. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with CSS inheritance.  The unordered list that contains "Company Price" is not displaying as a block element.  As a result, unless you're directly hovering over the text, it won't register the hover event.  According to Chrome debugger, it is trying to implement `display: block;`, but something else is overriding it.  This is almost certainly due to the list inheriting the style properties of all its ancestor lists.

I don't think there's an easy fix for this.  There are a couple of other buggy elements about the menu which are probably down to related issues.

Comment: actually this is the first time i'm creating an advanced navigation bar like this from scratch. I'm also new to jquery. I will check on the CSS inheritance and let you know. Thank you.